# Image can only be edited by putting 'img' after div html and css

Tags: html, css, image

I am building a website and tried to resize a div image in my CSS file, although I was unable to do this. I fixed this issue by putting img after the div name in the CSS file. When building previous websites, I have not had to do this, is there a fix or am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will provide an example below. Thanks :)

*Image will not resize*

HTML

```
<div class="example_image">
    <img src="example.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.example_image{
    width: 333px;
    height: 333px;
}
```

*CSS that ***does*** let me resize my image*

```
.example_image img{
    width: 333px;
    height: 333px;
}
```

Comment: The way you have it working is exactly how you are supposed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this

```
.example_image{
    width: 333px;
    height: 333px;
}
```

you are just resizing the div where the image resides. The image stays small in a resized div.

And this

```
.example_image img{
    width: 333px;
    height: 333px;
}
```

does explicitly resize the image. As the div can't stay small after that, it's resized too.

> When building previous websites, I have not had to do this, is there a fix or am I doing something wrong?

Can only be true if you did still set width and height to inherit for img, like this:

```css
.example_image{
    width: 333px;
    height: 333px;
}
.example_image>img{
   width:inherit;
   height:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="example_image">
    <img src="example.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Such a stupid mistake on my part! That makes sense now, Thanks for clearing things up.

Answer (score -1):

1. U can use css for div background-image: url('[path u pic]'); background-size: cover;
2. U can use css for img object-fit: cover; this not work ie 11 and older.